# Extra bytes are added when I run my compressed file in my decompression method

Tags: java, compression, lzw

I'm working with text files here. My LZW decompression doesn't seem to work correctly. Something is wrong when I try to decompress my compressed file back: I get **extra bytes** added to the text file after decompression. As of now, I found the sequence of values that's causing the issue, it's the * (star character)

For example, When I have a text file containing this following sentence:

```
*** Hello ***
```

Here's how my decompression works (I'm showing only 2 iterations):

```
#1 iteration
priorword = 42
currword = 256
Added in dict: 256: ** 

Wrote in file: **

#2 iteration
priorword = 256
currword = 32
Added in dict: 257: **_     (_ means space)
Write in file: **


We know have in file: ****_
```

What could be wrong here, an extra star gets added because as you can see the original file has three stars.

After decompression, `I get: **** Hello **`

A star * from the right is added to the left, how could this be?

Decompression method:

```
public void LZW_Decompress(String input) throws IOException {
        // DictSize builds up to 4k, Array_Char holds these values
        Array_char = new String[4096];

        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            dictionary.put(i, Character.toString((char) i));
            Array_char[i] = Character.toString((char) i);
        }

        // Read input as uncompressed file & Write out compressed file
        RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile(input, "r");
        RandomAccessFile out = new RandomAccessFile(input.replace(
                ".lzw", ""), "rw");

        try {
            // Gets the first word in code and outputs its corresponding char
            buffer[0] = in.readByte();
            buffer[1] = in.readByte();
            priorword = getvalue(buffer[0], buffer[1], onleft);
            onleft = !onleft;
            out.writeBytes(Array_char[priorword]);

            // Reads every 3 bytes and generates corresponding characters
            while (true) {
                if (onleft) {
                    buffer[0] = in.readByte();
                    buffer[1] = in.readByte();
                    currword = getvalue(buffer[0], buffer[1], onleft);
                } else {
                    buffer[2] = in.readByte();
                    currword = getvalue(buffer[1], buffer[2], onleft);
                }
                onleft = !onleft;

                if (currword >= dictSize) {
                    if (dictSize < 4096) {
                        Array_char[dictSize] = Array_char[priorword]
                                + Array_char[priorword].charAt(0);
                    }
                    dictSize++;
                    out.writeBytes(Array_char[priorword]
                            + Array_char[priorword].charAt(0));
                } else {
                    if (dictSize < 4096) {
                        Array_char[dictSize] = Array_char[priorword]
                                + Array_char[currword].charAt(0);
                    }
                    dictSize++;
                    out.writeBytes(Array_char[currword]);
                }
                priorword = currword;
            }
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question. The problem is probably one of your compression or decompression code, but it could also be in your display logic. Without seeing any of the code, all we can do is **guess**.

Comment: You're right sorry